# How do I check if Mapserver is installed or not?

Tags: mapserver, installation

I have installed MS4W (full) and choose port 8080 because on port 80 i have already installed IIS7. Now installation of MS4W is successful , but how i check ? I put http://localhost:8080/ in my browser, but i could not see the page.

any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

check that the mapserv.exe is in the apache\cgi-bin folder

then try this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe
```

if you see this result:

> No query information to decode. QUERY_STRING is set, but empty.

then it is installed correctly

also, use the command line  and cd to that folder and execute

> mapserv -v

to see if you it is missing some dependencies (it has allot..). it should result in something like:

> C:\OSGeo4W\apache\cgi-bin>mapserv -v
>   MapServer version 6.4.1 OUTPUT=GIF OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG OUTPUT=KML SUPPORTS=PR
>   OJ SUPPORTS=GD SUPPORTS=AGG SUPPORTS=FREETYPE SUPPORTS=CAIRO SUPPORTS=SVG_SYMBOL
>   S SUPPORTS=SVGCAIRO SUPPORTS=ICONV SUPPORTS=FRIBIDI SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER SUPPORTS
>   =WMS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WFS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WFS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WCS_SERVER SUPPORTS
>   =SOS_SERVER SUPPORTS=FASTCGI SUPPORTS=THREADS SUPPORTS=GEOS INPUT=JPEG INPUT=POS
>   TGIS INPUT=OGR INPUT=GDAL INPUT=SHAPEFILE

restart the server if you add after you have all the dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your server is started. Maybe, restart it and check again http://localhost:8080/

By the way, you should check if *Listen 8080* is written into /ms4w/Apache/conf/httpd.conf.
If not write it and restart your webserver

Comment: To check that MapServer is installed you don't need to also have a web server running.  That's the next step ~ to check if you have a  MapServer service running.